# Why is the ESP32 GND voltage different than the GND of the power supply?

Tags: voltage, usb, ground, esp32

I'm using a USB 2.0 hub to power one ESP32 NodeMCU. From the hub I'm also extracting the VCC and the GND (HUB->USB cable->Micro DIY female socket->VCC+GND). The voltage difference between the GND pins of the NodeMCU is zero, but the voltage difference between the GND pins and the GND in the female socket is 0.03V.

I'm trying to power another device with 5V from the same power supply and initiate link  (at 3.3V) between the device and the ESP32, but I need a common GND.

I guess that the NodeMCU regulates the power it receives to 3.3V regardless of what it gets from the USB power supply, but why the GND is different?

Here is the setup. The voltage difference between the two red wires is zero. The voltage difference between the black and any of the red wires is ~0.03V.

[image: ESP GND Pins]
[image: Overall View]
[image: USB Female]

Comment: guess the pin has a little resistance. 0.03V is not much, you should be fine.

Comment: Wires have resistance and if current flows there will be voltage drop. But what exactly happens in your case needs a diagram or maybe a photo, and some information how much current flows that creates the voltage drop. If it's 1mA there is a problem, if there is 1A, that is likely normal.

Comment: There is no load at all at any pin, I just use my multi-meter to check the difference between the GPIO GND pins and the micro socket GND.

Comment: Please add a schematic or a photo shoot of your setup and specify exactly where you are measuring.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question, I have attached same images.

Comment: Usually when there is differences in GND (or better said return plane) level, something is wrong. Like disturbances because of ground loop etc. The USB connector seems suspecting.